# About shorthand notation for conditional pattern (Paul Wellin "Essentials of Programming in Mathematica")

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-test

I am reading Paul Wellin's "Essentials of Programming in Mathematica".

Mr. Wellin wrote the following in his book:

> There is a convenient shorthand notation for conditional patterns that is commonly used. The condition *`expr_ /; test`* can be shortened to *`expr_?test`*.

But,

```
MatchQ[Range[10], {s__/;NumberQ[s]}]
```

returns an error and `False`. And,

```
MatchQ[Range[10], {s__?NumberQ}]
```

returns `True`.

Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`__?test` is not a shorthand for `s__ /; test[s]` in the sense that it is an alias. There are major differences that one needs to be aware of.

The third bullet point under "Details" in the documentation for `PatternTest` (`?`) is this:

> In a form such as __?test, every element in the sequence matched by __
>   must yield True when test is applied.

`MatchQ[Range[10], {s__ /; NumberQ[s]}]` will evaluate

```
NumberQ[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

This will give an error (and return `False`) because `NumberQ` hasn't been defined to take that many arguments. You can fix it, in a sense, like this:

```
MatchQ[Range[10], {s__ /; NumberQ[{s}]}]
```

but now it returns `False` because `NumberQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]` sees a list, which is not a number.

To actually get what we want using this method, we have to do this:

```
MatchQ[Range[10], {s__ /; AllTrue[{s}, NumberQ]}]
```

`__?test` is much shorter for this type of test, but as we have seen it is not a shorthand in the sense that we can use it as a drop-in replacement wherever we want. `?` essentially does the `AllTrue[{s}, test]` part for us.

Comment: Thank you very much, C. E.

Answer (score 9):

In short: you are confusing `Blank[]` (`_`) and `BlankSequence[]` (`__`). (There is also `BlankNullSequence[]` (`___`), but I shall skip talking about that to keep it short.)

What Wellin said about the patterns involving `Blank[]` (`_`) is mostly true, in that one has the choice of using `Condition` (`/;`) or `PatternTest` (`?`). So, you can do `n_?NumberQ` (the form often preferred for relatively simple expression tests) or `n_ /; NumberQ[n]` (more often used if the expression test is sufficiently complicated, e.g. `n_ /; NumberQ[n] && Positive[n]`). It is possible to express one in terms of the other, but the preferences I gave are common.

In your attempt, you were trying to use `/;` with `BlankSequence[]` (`__`); recall that `__` is supposed to match **one or more** things, when the expression test `NumberQ[]` can only take *one* argument. So `NumericQ[s]` will choke if `s` was e.g. `1, 2`, as you are now trying to give it two arguments.

In contrast, the pattern `s__?NumberQ` is fine; it is the way to test that `s` is **one or more things** that satisfy the expression test `NumericQ[]`.

If you had really insisted on using `/;` for this, one way in this case is to use something like `VectorQ[]`:

```
MatchQ[Range[10], {s__} /; VectorQ[{s}, NumberQ]]
```

Comment: (I am writing from a smartphone, so please edit my answer if the formatting looks screwy on desktop.)

Comment: Thank you very much, J. M. is computer-less.